# Как передавать параметры при вызове команды через Plesk REST API?

Tags: php, json, rest, parallel, plesk

Хочу установить автоответчик для существующего e-mail адреса на сервере через Plesk REST API
Пробую через вызов команды:

```
function setRequest($url, $headers, $post_fields)
{       
  $post_fields = json_encode( (array) $post_fields );
  $ch = curl_init($url); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);    
  $response = curl_exec($ch); 
  curl_close($ch);
  return json_decode( $response, true );
}

var_dump( setRequest(
  'https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443/api/v2/cli/autoresponder/call',
  array(
    'X-API-Key: c1986243-c4b7-0fc3-d543-67u9ad3a000a',
  ), 
  array(
    'params'=> array(
      '--update',
      'mail' => 'administrator@mydomen.ru',
    ),
  )
) );
```

получаю в ответ:

```
array(3) {
  ["code"]=>
  int(1)
  ["stdout"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["stderr"]=>
  string(135) "Unknown option 'administrator@mydomen.ru': /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/api-cli/autoresponder.php --update >>>administrator@mydomen.ru"
}
```

как правильно передавать параметры при вызове (call) конкретной команды? что-то нигде не нахожу в документации разъяснений по формату JSON массива.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё просто:

```
var_dump( setRequest(
    'https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443/api/v2/cli/autoresponder/call',
    array(
        'X-API-Key: c1986243-c4b7-0fc3-d543-67u9ad3a000a',
    ), 
    array(
        'params'=> array(
            '--update',
            '-mail',
            'administrator@mydomen.ru',
            '-status',
            'true',
            '-subject',
            'Re: this subject text',
            '-text',
            'This is text email message!',
        ),
    )
) );
```

Параметры пишутся как элементы массива по порядку - так как бы они шли в команде CLI, см. https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/cli-linux/using-command-line-utilities/autoresponder-mail-autoresponders.39140/